# MSSQL There are no primary or candidate keys in the referenced table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm creating 3 tables (1 parent and 2 child) and trying to set foreign keys but I'm getting this error:

> There are no primary or candidate keys in the referenced table.

```
CREATE TABLE WEATHER_FORECASTS(
    WEATHER_ID tinyint NOT NULL,
    TOWN_ID char(2) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(WEATHER_ID, TOWN_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE WEATHER(
    WEATHER_ID tinyint NOT NULL REFERENCES WEATHER_FORECASTS(WEATHER_ID),
    WEATHER_TYPE varchar(20) NOT NULL
    PRIMARY KEY(WEATHER_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE TOWNS(
    TOWN_ID char(2) NOT NULL REFERENCES WEATHER_FORECASTS(TOWN_ID),
    TOWN_NAME varchar(20) NOT NULL
);
```

Comment: It seems like you misunderstood on which end a foreign key constraint goes. It's the referencing side, not the referenced one! So presumably you want to put two (different) foreign key constraints in `weather_forecasts` referencing `weather` or `towns`. (But `towns` also still misses a (primary) key. Possibly you forgot a primary key constraint on `town_id` there.) If this isn't a misunderstanding of concepts on your side, you need to elaborate on what you actually want to achieve (on the logical level, not the nonworking solution to it) as that isn't clear then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Sticky Bit says you have the Foreign Key the wrong way round, you should have two foreign keys in the weather_forecasts table referencing the tables weather & towns:

```
CREATE TABLE TOWNS(
    TOWN_ID char(2) NOT NULL,
    TOWN_NAME varchar(20) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(TOWN_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE WEATHER(
    WEATHER_ID tinyint NOT NULL,
    WEATHER_TYPE varchar(20) NOT NULL
    PRIMARY KEY(WEATHER_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE WEATHER_FORECASTS(
    WEATHER_ID tinyint NOT NULL REFERENCES WEATHER(WEATHER_ID),
    TOWN_ID char(2) NOT NULL REFERENCES TOWNS(TOWN_ID),
    PRIMARY KEY(WEATHER_ID, TOWN_ID)
);
```

You may want to consider putting Indexes on those two foreign keys in the WEATHER_FORECASTS table to enhance performance.

Comment: You'll only need an index on Weather_Forecasts.Town_ID as Weather_ID is the first column in the primary key, which is the clustered index.